# HttpEventType.UploadProgress is only being called once, event.loaded and event.total are equal so the progress is immediately 100%

Tags: node.js, angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient, angular11

I have a method that creates a new post. This post includes uploading a video.

```
createPost(formDirective: FormGroupDirective): void {
 if (
      this.postForm.valid &&
      this.user?.fullName &&
      this.user?.imageUrl &&
      this.fileToUpload
    ) {
      const val = this.postForm.value;
      this.isLoading = true;
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('videoUrl', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
      formData.append('fullName', this.user.fullName);
      formData.append('imageUrl', this.user.imageUrl);
      formData.append('title', val.title);

      this.postsService
        .createPostWithVideoUpload(formData)
        .subscribe((event) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress && event.total) {
            console.log(event.total, event.loaded);
            this.progress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
          }
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log('Video successfully uploaded!', event.body);
            formDirective.resetForm();
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.fileToUpload = null;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.progress = 0;
            }, 1500);
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

This is my api call method in the PostsService. I'm using Node.js and Express.js on the backend and I'm uploading the video to Google Cloud Storage.

```
  createPostWithVideoUpload(data: any) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/post/upload`, data, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return response;
        })
      );
  }
```

I want to show the progress of the upload to the user using a progress bar. Uploading the video is working fine but the progress is immediately 100 because event.loaded is equal to event.total right away which is not supposed to be the case.